# Is there a way to get additional data, able to get Buffer and RemoteEndPoint

Tags: c#, udp, reactive

Using reactive extension, I am able to get Buffer and RemoteEndPoint from 
built in class "UdpReceiveResult" under "System.Net.Sockets".

```
 public static IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> UdpStream(IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        return Observable.Using(() => new UdpClient(endpoint),
            udpClient => Observable.Defer(() =>
                udpClient.ReceiveAsync().ToObservable()).Repeat());
    }

 var stream = UdpStream(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514));
        stream.Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Buffer)));
```

I need to filter UDP data based on "Facility", "Priority", "Time" and also need to get these data for a log like below as shown as "Visual Syslog Server",

[image]

What I see that class "UdpReceiveResult" only gave 2 properties,

[image]

Question: - 1. Is there any way to get other data like "Facility", etc for a UDP message?
2. If not, Is there any open source library to support this?

Thanks!

Comment: UDP message by itself is just array of bytes, without any meaning. To extract meaning from it you should know a format of data. In this case messages are syslog messages and so you need to parse them from `Buffer` yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Evk.  When I m doing `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Buffer)`, then I m getting a string like _<38>Nov 30 19:49:41 MachineName Application Name:Message Content_ which contains message as well as received date time, but not seeing "Facility" or "Priority"

Comment: Do you have any example code to parse syslog message, please share. Thanks Again!!!

Comment: Nope I don't have, but you might look up some library which can parse syslog for .NET